# How to install shapely for python 2.6 (Mac) NOT 2.7?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, shapely

I'm trying to use **Polygonizer** plugin inside QGIS, but it needs **Shapely** to work. I've installed Shapely (pip install Shapely) but that's for **python 2.7**. QGIS works with **python 2.6** (on Snow Leopard) and I can't find previous installers for it. Maybe I'm missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are using the [KyngChaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/) version of QGIS and thus the GEOS library is installed in /Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/

Download the [Shapely Python package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely/1.2.16) from PyPI or [Shapely](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely) from github and untar.

Then, in the terminal:

```
cd -> shapely folder
LDFLAGS=`/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/bin/geos-config --libs`
CFLAGS=`/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/bin/geos-config --cflags` 
python setup.py install
```

Comment: Thanks gene. All your assumptions are correct. I did everything as you suggested, though used "sudo python setup.py install" instead. But it still installs it for python 2.7. "Installed /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Shapely-1.2.16-py2.7.egg"

Comment: it is because you use the 2.7 version you have installed and not the installed version of Python on Snow Leopard which is 2.6. QGIS uses this version. It is a path problem

Answer (score 1):

You basically have to use the corresponding versions of either `easy_install` or `pip`. Unless you installed `pip` in the Apple-supplied Python, it will only work with the 2.7 version (assuming you installed it there), so you must use `easy_install`. Try doing `sudo /usr/bin/easy_install shapely`, which will install shapely using the `easy_install` located in /usr/bin/.

Now, if you have updated your OS X to Lion or Mountain Lion, the Apple-supplied Python will be some earlier version of 2.7. Try uninstalling QGIS and then installing it again. I read somewhere that QGIS will recognize both 2.6 and 2.7 Apple-supplied Python versions.