# Does anyone have a shapely install for python "dummies" guide?

Tags: qgis, mac, shapely

I have read both questions in regard to installing shapely on a Mac (OS Mountain Lion) and haven't been able to figure it out.  I'm not familiar with python syntax and am just trying to get shapely installed so I can use the polygonizer plugin in QGIS.

I download and untar shapely to my downloads folder, but then I have no idea where to put it.  I tried to put in some of the script from [How to install shapely for python 2.6 (Mac) NOT 2.7?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45346/how-to-install-shapely-for-python-2-6-mac-not-2-7) and http://tumblr.pauladamsmith.com/post/17663153373/howtoinstallgdalshapely, but all I get is "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" when I paste it into the QGIS python console.  Example of something I tried:

> > > cd -> '/Users/blablabla/Downloads/Shapely-1.2.17'
> > >         File "", line 1
> > >           cd -> '/Users/blablabla/Downloads/Shapely-1.2.17'
> > >               ^
> > >       SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> > >       LDFLAGS=`/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/bin/geos-config --libs`
> > >         File "", line 1
> > >           LDFLAGS=`/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/bin/geos-config --libs`
> > >                    ^
> > >       SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> > >       CFLAGS=`/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/bin/geos-config --cflags` 
> > >         File "", line 1
> > >           CFLAGS=`/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/bin/geos-config --cflags`
> > >                   ^
> > >       SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> > >       python setup.py install
> > >         File "", line 1
> > >           python setup.py install
> > >                      ^
> > >       SyntaxError: invalid syntax

If someone has a basic explanation of what I'm supposed to be doing, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shapely is a Python module and not a QGIS plugin. Therefore you must
use the terminal (Terminal.app) and not the QGIS python console to install shapely.

Comment: Thanks Gene. So I still have the folder untarred in my downloads folder.  Do I need to move it somewhere else before I run in the code in the terminal?  I am not getting any errors when I run it now, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything and QGIS still doesn't recognize shapely.ops.

Comment: Shapely must be installed in the Python site-packages folder with the command python setup.py install (see the first link)