# More Efficient Spatial join in Python without QGIS, ArcGIS, PostGIS, etc

Tags: spatial-join, fiona, typeerror

I'm attempting to do a spatial join much like the example here: [Is there a python option to "join attributes by location"?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75524/is-there-a-python-option-to-join-attributes-by-location). However, that approach seems really inefficient / slow. Even running this with a modest 250 points takes almost 2 minutes and it fails entirely on shapefiles with > 1,000 points. Is there a better approach? I'd like to do this entirely in Python without using ArcGIS, QGIS, etc.

I'd also be interested to know if it's possible to SUM attributes (i.e. population) of all the points that fall within a polygon and join that quantity to the polygon shapefile.

Here is the code I'm trying to convert. I get an error on line 9:

`poly['properties']['score'] += point['properties']['score']`

which says:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'float'.

If I replace the "+=" with "=" it runs fine but that doesn't sum the fields. I've also tried making these as integers but that fails as well.

```
with fiona.open(poly_shp, 'r') as n: 
  with fiona.open(point_shp,'r') as s:
    outSchema = {'geometry': 'Polygon','properties':{'region':'str','score':'float'}}
    with fiona.open (out_shp, 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', outSchema, crs) as output:
        for point in s:
            for poly in n:
                if shape(point['geometry']).within(shape(poly['geometry'])):  
                    poly['properties']['score']) += point['properties']['score'])
                    output.write({
                        'properties':{
                            'region':poly['properties']['NAME'],
                            'score':poly['properties']['score']},
                        'geometry':poly['geometry']})
```

Comment: I think you should edit your second question out of here so that this one remains focussed on what I assume is the more important question to you. The other can be researched/asked separately.

Answer (score 39):

Fiona returns Python dictionaries and you can not use  `poly['properties']['score']) += point['properties']['score'])` with a dictionary.

Example of summing attributes using the references given by Mike T:

[image]

```
# read the shapefiles 
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import shape
polygons = [pol for pol in fiona.open('poly.shp')]
points = [pt for pt in fiona.open('point.shp')]
# attributes of the polygons
for poly in polygons:
   print poly['properties'] 
OrderedDict([(u'score', 0)])
OrderedDict([(u'score', 0)])
OrderedDict([(u'score', 0)])

# attributes of the points
for pt in points:
    print i['properties']
 OrderedDict([(u'score', 1)]) 
 .... # (same for the 8 points)
```

Now, we can use two methods, with or without a spatial index:

#### 1: without

```
# iterate through points 
 for i, pt in enumerate(points):
     point = shape(pt['geometry'])
     #iterate through polygons
     for j, poly in enumerate(polygons):
        if point.within(shape(poly['geometry'])):
             # sum of attributes values
             polygons[j]['properties']['score'] = polygons[j]['properties']['score'] + points[i]['properties']['score']
```

#### 2: with a [R-tree index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) (you can use  [pyrtree](https://code.google.com/p/pyrtree/) or [rtree](http://toblerity.org/rtree/))

```
# Create the R-tree index and store the features in it (bounding box)
 from rtree import index
 idx = index.Index()
 for pos, poly in enumerate(polygons):
       idx.insert(pos, shape(poly['geometry']).bounds)

#iterate through points
for i,pt in enumerate(points):
  point = shape(pt['geometry'])
  # iterate through spatial index
  for j in idx.intersection(point.coords[0]):
      if point.within(shape(polygons[j]['geometry'])):
            polygons[j]['properties']['score'] = polygons[j]['properties']['score'] + points[i]['properties']['score']
```

Result with the two solutions:

```
for poly in polygons:
   print poly['properties']    
 OrderedDict([(u'score', 2)]) # 2 points in the polygon
 OrderedDict([(u'score', 1)]) # 1 point in the polygon
 OrderedDict([(u'score', 1)]) # 1 point in the polygon
```

What is the difference ?

- Without the index, you must iterate through all the geometries (polygons and  points).
- With a bounding spatial index ([Spatial Index RTree](http://horicky.blogspot.be/2010/02/spatial-index-rtree.html)), you iterate only through the geometries which have a chance to intersect with your current geometry ('filter' which can save a considerable amount of calculations and time...)
- but a Spatial Index is not a magic wand. When a very large part of the dataset has to be retrieved, a Spatial Index cannot give any speed benefit.

After:

```
schema = fiona.open('poly.shp').schema
with fiona.open ('output.shp', 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', schema) as output:
    for poly in polygons:
        output.write(poly)
```

To go further, look at [Using Rtree Spatial Indexing With OGR, Shapely, Fiona](http://snorf.net/blog/2014/05/12/using-rtree-spatial-indexing-with-ogr/)

Answer (score 22):

Additionally - geopandas now optionally includes `rtree` as a dependency, see the [github repo](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas)

So, instead of following all the (very nice) code above, you could simply do something like:

```
import geopandas
from geopandas.tools import sjoin
point = geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_file('point.shp') # or geojson etc
poly = geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_file('poly.shp')
pointInPolys = sjoin(point, poly, how='left')
pointSumByPoly = pointInPolys.groupby('PolyGroupByField')['fields', 'in', 'grouped', 'output'].agg(['sum'])
```

To get this snazzy functionality be sure to install the C-library [libspatialindex](http://libspatialindex.github.io/) first

EDIT: corrected package imports

Comment: I was under the impression `rtree` was optional. Doesn't that mean you need to install `rtree` as well as the `libspatialindex` C-library?

Comment: it's been a while but I think when I did this installing geopandas from github automatically added `rtree` when I had first installed `libspatialindex`... they've done a fairly major release since so I'm sure things have changed a bit

Comment: I just installed `geopandas` from pypa and needed to install `rtree` to get `sjoin` to work. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60014884/868724

Answer (score 9):

Use [Rtree](http://toblerity.org/rtree/) as an index to perform the much faster joins, then Shapely to do the spatial predicates to determine if a point is actually within a polygon. If done properly, this can be faster than most other GISes.

See examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24114565/327026) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14804366/327026).

The second part of your question concerning 'SUM', use a `dict` object to accumulate populations using a polygon id as the key. Although, this type of thing is done much more nicely with PostGIS.

Comment: Thank you @Mike T ... using the dict object or PostGIS are great suggestions. I'm still a little confused where I can incorporate Rtree in my code, however (included code above).

Answer (score 2):

This web page shows how to use a Bounding Box point-in-polygon search before the more expensive Within spatial query of Shapely.

[http://rexdouglass.com/fast-spatial-joins-in-python-with-a-spatial-index/](https://web.archive.org/web/20170614032931/http://rexdouglass.com/fast-spatial-joins-in-python-with-a-spatial-index/)

Comment: Thanks @klewis ... any chance you can help with the second part? To sum the point attributes (e.g. population) that fall within the polygons I tried something similar to code below but it threw an error. if shape(school['geometry']).within(shape(neighborhood['geometry'])):  
   neighborhood['properties']['population'] += schools['properties']['population']

Comment: If you open neighborhood in 'r' mode, it might be read-only. Do both shapefiles have field population? What line # is throwing the error? Good luck.

Comment: Thank you again @klewis ... I've added my code above and explained the error. Also, I've been playing around with rtree and I'm still little confused where I would add this into the code above. Sorry to be a such a bother.

Comment: Try this, seems adding None to an int is causing the error. poly_score = poly['properties']['score']) point_score = point['properties']['score'])

if point_score:
  if poly_score
    poly['properties']['score']) += point_score
  else:
    poly['properties']['score']) = point_score