# Performing Spatial Join / match Points from dataframe to polygons using Python?

Tags: python, spatial-join, geopandas

I have a dataframe with coordinates and other attributes, and a shp file (the whole package with shx and dbf as well) with many polygons of neighborhoods. I need to match each point to which polygon it belongs to, and it would be for quite a large dataset.

### What I did find and why it didn't fit

I've found some suggested solutions online for it, and understood the best ways should be by using Fiona and Shapely, or GeoPandas, but:

**1.** Existing solutions (that I found) were all assuming I'm working with an shp file for the points as well, but I'm working with a **dataframe**. (I may be able to find out how to convert it to an shp file but I assume that will be redundant and not the most efficient).

**2.** Most solutions assumed the shp file has only one attribute, while mine has **many attributes**; or aimed at checking if points are in 1 polygon or not. I assume there must be a better way to assign points to the corresponding polygon than looping through this.

### Solutions I tried

I tried suggestions from the following pages:

- all of the solutions in the extensive answer here:
  [Check if a point falls within a multipolygon with Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208546/check-if-a-point-falls-within-a-multipolygon-with-python/208574)
  and these:
- [Find csv lat and long points in a shapefile polygon with geopandas spatial index](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230421/find-csv-lat-and-long-points-in-a-shapefile-polygon-with-geopandas-spatial-index)
- [Fastest way to join many points to many polygons in python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172144/fastest-way-to-join-many-points-to-many-polygons-in-python)
- [More Efficient Spatial join in Python without QGIS, ArcGIS, PostGIS, etc](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102933/more-efficient-spatial-join-in-python-without-qgis-arcgis-postgis-etc/103066#103066)
- https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/2016/Lesson3-spatial-join.html

#### Attempt 1: Fiona + Shapely

from [How to map a point to a polygon label from a shapefile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164571/how-to-map-a-point-to-a-polygon-label-from-a-shapefile):

```
import fiona 
from shapely.geometry import Point, shape  

NY_nbr_shpfile = 'taxi_zones.shp'

def coor_to_nbr(longit, lat, shape_file):
    mypoint = Point(longit, lat)   
    with fiona.open(NY_nbr_shpfile) as shp:
        polygons = [poly for poly in shp]
    poly_idx = [i for i, poly in enumerate(polygons)
                if mypoint.within(shape(poly['geometry']))]
    if poly_idx: print poly_idx
    if not poly_idx:
        return None
    else:
        # Take first polygon that overlaps since may overlap with several if on border
        match = polygons[poly_idx[0]]
        return match['properties']


### TRYING TO MATCH one-by-one, that didn't work:
print coor_to_nbr(-73.9868805930018, 40.7697167683218, NY_nbr_shpfile)
print coor_to_nbr( 40.722249, -73.997673, NY_nbr_shpfile) . ### just checking it's not opposite 
print coor_to_nbr( -73.977673,40.722249, NY_nbr_shpfile)`
```

This printed 'None' to everything I tried, but I know these points are inside one of the polygons.

#### Attempt 2: GeoPandas1

This is taken from the following url; I left the original points there just to see if it would even work, and it seems to not work for me - yielding at ValueError: need at least one array to concatenate.

```
#### https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190903/assign-a-point-to-polygon-using-pandas-and-shapely #### 
ny_nbr_shpfile = '/Users/tomer/Dropbox (Via)/Mapping data/New York/TLC Taxi Zones/taxi_zones (1)/taxi_zones.shp'

import pandas
import geopandas
import geopandas.tools
from shapely.geometry import Point

#### POLYGONS
# Load the polygons
polys = geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_file(ny_nbr_shpfile)


#### POINTS 
# Create a DataFrame with some cities, including their location
raw_data = [
    ("London", 51.5, -0.1),
    ("Paris", 48.9, 2.4),
    ("San Francisco", 37.8, -122.4),
]
points = pandas.DataFrame(raw_data, columns=["name", "latitude", "longitude"])
###print points
# Create the geometry column from the coordinates
# Remember that longitude is east-west (i.e. X) and latitude is north-south (i.e. Y)
points["geometry"] = points.apply(lambda row: Point(row["longitude"], row["latitude"]), axis=1)
del(points["latitude"], points["longitude"])
###print points
# Convert to a GeoDataFrame
points = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(points, geometry="geometry")

# Declare the coordinate system for the points GeoDataFrame
# GeoPandas doesn't do any transformations automatically when performing
# the spatial join. The layers are already in the same CRS (WGS84) so no
# transformation is needed.
points.crs = polys.crs
###print points.crs


#print nbrhoods
# Drop all columns except the name and polygon geometry

#boroughs = nbrhoods[["borough", "geometry"]]

# Perform the spatial join
result = geopandas.tools.sjoin(points, nbrhoods, how="left")
# Print the results...
print(result.head())
```

result: `ValueError: need at least one array to concatenate`. From researching this error, it seems that it happenned commonly when spatial join yields no results but it was supposed to be fixed by this version of GeoPandas. I assume it is fixed and it is another problem here.

#### Attempt 3: GeoPandas 2 : (similar)

```
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Point
import geopandas as gp
from geopandas.tools import sjoin

FRC1  = gp.read_file(ny_nbr_shpfile)


#trip = pd.read_csv('TripRecordsReporttrips.csv', sep=',',header=None, usecols=[0, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11],names=['TripID', 'Date', 'StartLat', 'StartLon','EndLat','EndLon'])


geometry = [Point(-73.9868805930018, 40.7697167683218),
            Point(-73.977673,40.722249)]
#geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(trip['StartLon'], trip['StartLat'])]
#geometry2 = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(trip['EndLon'], trip['EndLat'])]
#trip = trip.drop(['StartLon', 'StartLat','EndLon','EndLat'], axis=1)
trip = ['broadway 150', 'crosby 10']
crs = {'init' :'epsg:4326'}
starts = gp.GeoDataFrame(trip, crs=FRC1.crs , geometry=geometry)
#ends  = gp.GeoDataFrame(trip, crs=crs, geometry=geometry2)

#starts.head() ###print 


pointInPolys = sjoin(starts, FRC1, how='left',op="within")
```

### Reproduction Materials

Shapefiles for neighborhoods is the same as here: https://geo.nyu.edu/catalog/nyu_2451_36743

Example input for points:

Start Lng...................   Start Lat..................  End Lat ................... End Long................

-73.9446545764804   40.7796840845172    40.7693589967192    -73.9857926219702
-73.9574825763702   40.8116657733964    40.7834276940059    -73.9789965748787
-73.9574825763702   40.8116657733964    40.7839981278416    -73.9762181416154
-73.9938855171204   40.7355130703031    40.7112190324095    -73.9506489783525
-73.9634789898992   40.7588519932381    40.7544933950398    -73.9975795894861
-73.9907560497522   40.7364947075543    40.804403082633 -73.9372211694717
-73.9907560497522   40.7364947075543    40.804403082633 -73.9372211694717
-73.9939170330763   40.7464936766106    40.7191759823283    -73.9889881387353
-73.9907560497522   40.7364947075543    40.804403082633 -73.9372211694717
-73.9831633865833   40.718557218786 40.6432838990509    -73.7899511307478
-73.9887668564916   40.7186952022837    40.7759590522127    -73.9807621389627

---

*Points put into an array just for experiments - even through half of them are lat/long and half are long/lat, I'm trying both to see if the problem might be that the functions take it as one way and not the other.

[(-73.9446545764804, 40.7796840845172)
(40.7693589967192 ,-73.9857926219702)
(-73.9574825763702, 40.8116657733964 )
(40.7834276940059 ,-73.9789965748787 )
(-73.9574825763702, 40.8116657733964 )
(40.7839981278416 ,-73.9762181416154 )
(-73.9938855171204, 40.7355130703031 )
(40.7112190324095 ,-73.9506489783525 )
(-73.9634789898992, 40.7588519932381 )
(40.7544933950398 ,-73.9975795894861 )
(-73.9907560497522, 40.7364947075543 )
(40.804403082633   ,-73.9372211694717 )
(-73.9907560497522, 40.7364947075543 )
(40.804403082633   ,-73.9372211694717 )
(-73.9939170330763, 40.7464936766106 )
(40.7191759823283 ,-73.9889881387353 )
(-73.9907560497522, 40.7364947075543 )
(40.804403082633 ,-73.9372211694717 )
(-73.9831633865833, 40.718557218786 )
(40.6432838990509 ,-73.7899511307478 )
(-73.9887668564916, 40.7186952022837 )
(40.7759590522127, -73.9807621389627)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply a projection problem. The CRS of the taxi_zones.shp file is

```
c = fiona.open('taxi_zones.shp')
c.crs
{u'lon_0': -74, u'datum': u'NAD83', u'y_0': 0, u'no_defs': True, u'proj': u'lcc', u'x_0': 300000, u'units': u'us-ft', u'lat_2': 41.03333333333333, u'lat_1': 40.66666666666666, u'lat_0': 40.16666666666666}
```

That corresponds to [EPSG 2263](http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/nad83-new-york-long-island-ftus/) (NAD83 / New York Long Island (ftUS))

If I use the [nyu_2451_36743.shp (nyu_2451_36743_WGS84.zip)](https://archive.nyu.edu/handle/2451/36743) shapefile (in WGS84 projection)

```
c = fiona.open('nyu_2451_36743.shp')
c.crs
{u'no_defs': True, u'datum': u'WGS84', u'proj': u'longlat'}
```

Then

```
 NY_nbr_shpfile ='nyu_2451_36743.shp'
 ....
 print coor_to_nbr(-73.9868805930018, 40.7697167683218, NY_nbr_shpfile)
[141]
OrderedDict([(u'OBJECTID', 142), (u'Shape_Leng', 0.03817589423), (u'Shape_Area', 7.565379e-05), (u'zone', u'Lincoln Square East'), (u'LocationID', 142), (u'borough', u'Manhattan')])
```

works

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much, Gene! true, the problem WAS indeed the PROJECTION type!
(between NAD83 and WGS84 projections).
It worked when I simply used the different versions of the files that are in the WGS84 projection, and also worked when I converted the projection to WGS84 within GeoPandas.