# geopandas error "minimums more than maximums"

Tags: python, spatial-join, geopandas

I posted this question on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34420285/merging-geodataframes-in-geopandas-crs-do-not-match?noredirect=1#comment56609513_34420285), but it seems that gis.stackexchange is the more appropriate platform.

I am trying to merge two geodataframes in geopandas (want to see which polygon each point is in).

The following code gets me an error ("`RTreeError: Coordinates must not have minimums more than maximums`").

I cannot find any explanation as to what this means and how to solve it. Any ideas?

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, mapping,shape
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame, read_file
#from geopandas.tools import overlay
from geopandas.tools import sjoin

print('Reading points...')
points=pd.read_csv(points_csv)
points['geometry'] = points.apply(lambda z: Point(z.Latitude, z.Longitude), axis=1)
PointsGeodataframe = gpd.GeoDataFrame(points)
print PointsGeodataframe.head()
print('Reading polygons...')
PolygonsGeodataframe = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(china_shapefile+".shp")
print PolygonsGeodataframe.head()
print('Merging GeoDataframes...')
merged=sjoin(PointsGeodataframe, PolygonsGeodataframe, how='left', op='intersects')

#merged = PointsGeodataframe.merge(PolygonsGeodataframe, left_on='iso_alpha2', right_on='ISO2', how='left')
print(merged.head(5))
```

Link to data for reproduction:
[Shapefile](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7wwmhtfivg4qvjg/AAC0Lr03SYH4XvPJledGpHxma?dl=0),
[GPS points](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8j8j6uyavi4jdnn/sample_map_data.csv?dl=0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many problems in your data (sample_map_data.csv) and in your script.

1) the sample_map_data.csv file contains 6 valid lines and 730 lines with ''

```
import pandas as pd  
points = pd.read_csv("sample_map_data.csv")
points.shape
(735, 3)
```

Resulting in the error "RTreeError: Coordinates must not have minimums more than maximums"

The right result should be .

```
points = pd.read_csv("sample_map_data.csv",nrows= 5)
points.shape
(5, 3)
print(points)
Latitude   Longitude  Heat
0  23.124700  113.282776   100
1  22.618574  113.999634    80
2  23.694332  113.049316    70
3  23.809973  114.735718    90
4  21.815098  110.961914    80)
```

2) In Shapely, a Point is defined by Point(x,y) and not Point(y,x) so

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
points['geometry'] = points.apply(lambda z: Point(z.Longitude, z.Latitude), axis=1)
import geopandas as gpd
PointsGeodataframe = gpd.GeoDataFrame(points)
print(PointsGeodataframe)
Latitude      Longitude    Heat         geometry
0  23.124700  113.282776   100  POINT (113.282776 23.1247)
1  22.618574  113.999634    80  POINT (113.999634 22.618574)
2  23.694332  113.049316    70  POINT (113.049316 23.694332)
3  23.809973  114.735718    90  POINT (114.735718 23.809973)
4  21.815098  110.961914    80  POINT (110.961914 21.815098)
```

3) For Points in Polygons, look at [More Efficient Spatial join in Python without QGIS, ArcGIS, PostGIS, etc](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/165413)): no need of `op='intersects'`

```
PolygonsGeodataframe = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file("CHN_adm1.shp")
PointsGeodataframe.crs = PolygonsGeodataframe.crs #same crs for the two layers
from geopandas.tools import sjoin
pointInPolys = sjoin(PointsGeodataframe, PolygonsGeodataframe, how='left') 
print(pointInPolys.head(5))
```

and it works.

Answer (score 19):

For the benefit of anyone else searching for this error message, one thing that can cause it is attempting to do a spatial join where the point coordinates contain nulls.

Comment: Thank you for this comment! Saved me a some debugging time.

Comment: That also saved me some debugging time.

Comment: I came back here twice in as many weeks because of this.  Shapely will allow `Point(nan,nan)` without complaints; make sure you check for / drop any such values and avoid this issue.

Comment: Hero saved me some debugging time.

Comment: Just adding to the list of comments saying that you saved me some debugging time

Answer (score 4):

To check if there are `Point(nan, nan)`:

```
gdf.is_valid
```

To clean them up:

```
gdf = gdf[gdf.is_valid]
```