# How to Convert 3D coordinates to 2D coordinates for R-Tree?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, spatial-statistics, shapely

I am trying to implement a bounding box via a spatial index and get an error stating that I must either provide coordinates as either **(minx, miny, maxx, maxy)** or **(x,y)** for 2D indexes.

I've tried using the R-Tree example from this thread:  [More Efficient Spatial join in Python without QGIS, ArcGIS, PostGIS, etc](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102933/more-efficient-spatial-join-in-python-without-qgis-arcgis-postgis-etc/165413#165413)

The first time I try to do a spatial index, I have the following value for a point ("Z" is the current value of "i" before my code breaks):

**POINT Z (11.52951677300007 0.7729100360000416 -50000)**

How can I gracefully get rid of the Z-coordinate to pass on as a 2D coordinate in my "for j" statement?  Code snippet is below:

```
    from rtree import index
    idx = index.Index() #Create an R-Tree index and store the features in it (bounding box)
    for pos, poly in enumerate(polygons):
        idx.insert(pos, shape(poly['geometry']).bounds)

        for i,pt in enumerate(points):  #iterate through the points
            point = shape(pt['geometry'])
            for j in idx.intersection(point.coords[0]):  #iterate through spatial index
                if point.within(shape(multi[j]['geometry'])):
                    discoveredBuildings.append(point['id'])
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a pure Python problem

With shapely, your 3D point is represented by

```
pt3D = Point(11.52951677300007,0.7729100360000416, -50000)
list(pt3D.coords)
[(11.52951677300007, 0.7729100360000416, -50000.0)]
```

Using slicing for example (there are others solutions)

```
pt2D = Point(list(pt3D.coords)[0][:2])
print pt2D
POINT (11.52951677300007 0.7729100360000416)
```

Or

```
 Pt2D = Point(pt3D.x, pt3D.y)
 print Pt2D
 POINT (11.52951677300007 0.7729100360000416)
```

Or ...

Comment: haha... nice ! +1