# GeoDjango - faster way to use polygon.crosses?

Tags: python, geodjango, django

I have a polygon and a line segment. I want to know if the line segment is both inside and outsize the polygon.  Using "prepared" has helped but it's still no where near fast enough.  how can i speed up this process? I really want to use geoDjango but I'm all ears if there is something else out there (still in python).

```
myPolygon = Polygon(....)
myPreparedPolygon = myPolygon.prepared
myPreparedPolygon.crosses(lineAB)
```

:::EDIT::: I'm using "myPreparedPolygon.crosses(line)" because it's a prepared polygon.  Using "line.crossed(myPreparedPolygon)" with not work.

[image: Does segment AB cross the polygon?]

Answer (score 1):

GeoDjango is based on the [GEOS](https://trac.osgeo.org/geos) library as [Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html). If you don't use Django it is more interesting to work with this module (many examples in GIS SE)

Following the explanations of [GEOS: Prepared Geometries](https://trac.osgeo.org/geos/wiki/PreparedGeometry), a Prepared Geometry is a spatial predicate (only True or False). Geometries are "prepared"  ala SQL for efficient batch operations ([Efficient batch operations for Shapely](https://sgillies.net/2009/01/26/efficient-batch-operations-for-shapely.html))

```py
myPolygon.intersects(lineAB) 
lineAB.intersects(myPolygon) 
myPreparedPolygont.intersects(lineAB)
```

With Shapely

```py
from shapely.prepared import prep
myPolygon.intersects(lineAB) 
lineAB.intersects(myPolygon) 
prep(myPolygon).intersects(line)
```

give the same result, `True`.

The only difference is the speed if you work with many objects (see [Efficient batch operations for Shapely](https://sgillies.net/2009/01/26/efficient-batch-operations-for-shapely.html))  as a Spatial Index ([More Efficient Spatial join in Python without QGIS, ArcGIS, PostGIS, etc](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102933/more-efficient-spatial-join-in-python-without-qgis-arcgis-postgis-etc/103066#103066)).

> The performance gains from using PreparedGeometry in real-world situations can be dramatic - up to 40 times improvement in speed ([PreparedGeometry - efficient batch spatial operations for JTS](http://lin-ear-th-inking.blogspot.be/2007/08/preparedgeometry-efficient-batch.html) )

With GeoDjango or Shapely

```py
res = [line for line in lines if myPolygon.intersects(line)]
# and
res = [line for line in lines if myPreparedPolygont.intersects(line)]
```

In your example, the only solution (or use a Spatial Index) is the result of

With GeoDjango or Shapely

```py
 len(lineAB.intersection(myPolygon))
 2 # -> MultiLineString
```

[image]

Compare with the upper line (green) where the`len = 1` (simple LineString)

Or the inverse with

```
lineAB.difference(myPolygon)
```

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that prepared geometries with shapely can be faster than GeoDjango?