# Filter coordinates outside the boundary of a shapefile

Tags: qgis, python, shapefile, shapely

I have a dataframe that contains X & Y co-ordinates. Some of these coordinates are outside my country of interest, India. I'm looking for a way to filter out all the coordinates outside the shapefile of India. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Here's the code I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import shapefile
from shapely.geometry import Point 
from shapely.geometry import shape 

shp = shapefile.Reader("D:\Work\MOSDAC\ind.shp","r")
all_shapes = shp.shapes() 
all_records = shp.records()    

def InCountry(lo,la):
    point_to_check = (lo, la) 
    for i in range(len(all_shapes)):
        boundary = all_shapes[i] 
        if Point(point_to_check).within(shape(boundary)):
            #Inside country shape file
            return (1)
        else:
            #Outside country shape file
            #return (0) this doesn't work use pass instead   
            pass




final['X2'].apply(lambda x: float(x))

final['Y2'].apply(lambda x: float(x))

#Create copy of dataframe with only incountry coordinates
df_copy = final.apply(InCountry(final['X2'].tolist(),final['Y2'].tolist()))
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to filter the shapefile using GeoPandas's [`within`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.within.html) method of the [`GeoSeries`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.within.html) class:

```py
from os.path import normpath
from geopandas import read_file

path_to_points = normpath("C:/Users/taras/Python Scripts/geopandas/points.shp")
path_to_polygons = normpath("C:/Users/taras/Python Scripts/geopandas/union.shp")

points, polygons = read_file(path_to_points), read_file(path_to_polygons)

points_mask = points.within(polygons.loc[0, 'geometry'])

points_filtered = points.loc[points_mask]
```

---

**References:**

- [Filter a GeoPandas dataframe for points within a specific country](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282681/filter-a-geopandas-dataframe-for-points-within-a-specific-country)