# Clipping points with complex polygon geometry using GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, performance

I have a huge point dataset with almost 300.000 points and I want to intersect them with a country geometry that has a complex geometry (multiple islands and borders).
What I've done so far is to construct a GeoPandas dataframe and then clip it, however the process takes almost 50 minutes whereas if I perform the same task with ArcGIS the entire process takes only 43 seconds. I've been searching for a way to improve the process without success.

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    merged_data,
    crs='EPSG:4326',
    geometry=[Point(xy) for xy in zip(merged_data.longitude, merged_data.latitude)])
poly = country_boundary.geometry.unary_union
points_clip = gdf[gdf.geometry.intersects(poly)]
```

Comment: see [More Efficient Spatial join in Python without QGIS, ArcGIS, PostGIS, etc](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/165413/2581)

Answer (score 2):

Use `geopandas.clip` for clipping. That is an efficient way how to do so, especially with GeoPandas 0.8.0 and [pygeos](https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#using-the-optional-pygeos-dependency).

```py
points_clip = gpd.clip(gdf, country_boundary)
```