# Spatial join of building footprints with Shapely and Fiona

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap, shapely, fiona

I would like to do a spatial merge of the [address nodes](https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/28c023ec04794ad586c4d9f89db24a8b_0.zip?outSR=%7B%22wkid%22%3A102682%2C%22latestWkid%22%3A3452%7D&session=undefined) of *Baton Rouge* into their [surrounding building footprints](https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/d4684653de964f759f57bd05f75de64a_0.zip?outSR=%7B%22wkid%22%3A102682%2C%22latestWkid%22%3A3452%7D&session=undefined). Every building (polygon) should get the properties of the address (point).

Here is an visualization of the task:

[image: Visualization]

I've tried to use the shapely+fiona solution from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/75618/121512). I've only changed it that the polygon shapefile get's written with the point shapefile's properties (before it was the other way round).

```
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import shape
from copy import deepcopy

with fiona.open("Building_Footprint.shp", "r") as buildings: 

    with fiona.open("Street_Address.shp", "r") as addresses:

        outSchema = deepcopy(buildings.schema)
        outSchema['properties'].update(addresses.schema['properties'])
        print(outSchema)

        with fiona.open ("Joined.shp", "w", buildings.driver, outSchema, buildings.crs) as output:

            for address in addresses: 
                for building in buildings:
                    # check if point is in polygon and set attribute
                    if shape(address['geometry']).within(shape(building['geometry'])):
                        print("yes")
                        building['properties'] = address['properties']
                    # write out
                        output.write({                                 
                            'properties': building['properties'], 
                            'geometry': building['geometry']
                        })
```

But I'm getting `ValueError: Record does not match collection schema: odict_keys(['ID', ...]`

Why is it failing?

Comment: what happens when you print out the `outSchema` after you do `outSchema['properties'].update(addresses.schema['properties'])`

Comment: {'properties': OrderedDict([('ID', 'int:10'), ('AREA_SQFT', 'float:24.15'), ('HEIGHT_FEE', 'str:80'), ('NUMBER_FLO', 'str:80'), ('YEAR_BUILT', 'str:80'), ('ADDRESS_ID', 'int:10'), ('BUSINESS_N', 'str:99'), ('FULL_ADDRE', 'str:80'), ('CITY', 'str:80'), ('ADDRESS_JU', 'str:80'), ('STATE', 'str:80'), ('ZIP', 'int:10'), ('COUNTRY', 'str:80'), ('ADDRESS_AU', 'str:80'), ('SUBDIVISIO', 'str:80'), ('BUSINESS_I', 'str:80'), ('BUSINESS_1', 'str:80'), ('SERVICE_TY', 'str:80'), ('SERVICE_NA', 'str:80')]), 'geometry': 'Polygon'}

Comment: maybe delete the `'geometry': 'Polygon'` out of the outSchema