# How do I successfully install LeCos plug in for QGIS2.0 on a Mac?

Tags: qgis-plugins, installation, mac

I have been trying without success to install the LeCos plug in on QGIS2.0 on my Mac. I originally tried it on QGIS1.8 but was unable to install the dependent packages (PIL,scipy and numpy). I updated to QGIS 2.20 and successfully installed the packages, however I am still unable to install LeCos. THis is the message that comes up:

[image]

The packages are definitely installed because I checked by doing this in python:
[image]

Has anyone else installed it successfully?

Comment: You probably the one who commented on my blog. Your error is most likely related to wrong packaging and you need to contact the distributor. `_ni_support.py` is normally included in the scipy python base (http://tinyurl.com/pco2489), but apparently it was not successfully packaged into the kyngchaos sources

Comment: Yes that's me! Ok great thanks a lot for that info will give it a go and report back.

Comment: I thought downloading the packages from other sources might fix the problem. Unfortunately it hasn't.

Comment: Alternatively you could try to open a QGIS python shell and install scipy via pip. (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54674/how-to-install-the-python-module-shapely-for-qgis-use). Nathan also posted a guide for Win on his blog -> http://tinyurl.com/qcdq7fh Don't know if this will work on MAC though...