# QGIS Contour Plugin Says No Shapely; can import shapely in QGIS console

Tags: qgis, python, contour, shapely, numpy

I'm keen to create some contours (isochrones for a pedestrian 'ped-shed' catchment) from a point dataset in QGIS, using the **contour** plugin from the Plugins repository.

I installed the plugin, but restarting QGIS generated a popup saying that the plugin had been disabled because one or more of `shapely`, `matplotlib` and `numpy` were not installed.

Since other plugins already depend on numpy and matplotlib, it was clear that only `shapely` could be the problem. `pip install shapely` finished without a hitch, but re-opening QGIS again spat out the popup.

When I open the Python console in QGIS and type `import shapely`, it's found - as the screenshot below shows.

A trawl of the internet and of this SX yield mostly questions like [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54674/how-to-install-the-python-module-shapely-for-qgis-use) - i.e., people who missed the dependencies (as I did, but have remedied).

Has anybody seen this behaviour before? If so, how was it resolved?

Both Python (2.7) and QGIS (2.8.2 Wien) are 32-bit; running on Windows 7 ultimate.

[image]

Comment: OK, so it turns out that further detective work helped. QGIS Python console found shapely, contour didn't. QGIS is using its own version of Python (2.7.4) in [QGIS directory]\apps while my non-QGIS Python install - tailored to my non-QGIS work needs and **!important** is 2.7.9 in C:\Python27. Try installing shapely to theQGIS-sub-version-specific version of Python: it's a GIGANTIC PITFA. For the present I've bat-ed a toggle for Windows PATH and PYTHONPATH: switch to QGIS' Python when QGIS starts, else revert to proper Python. All just to run one plugin: plugin works real nice though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that while QGIS' Python console found shapely, `contour` didn't.

QGIS is using its own version of Python (2.7.4) in `QGIS directory`\apps while my non-QGIS Python install - tailored to my non-QGIS work needs and **!important** - is 2.7.9 in C:\Python27.

Shapely was installed into C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages but `contour` was blind to anything outside of **`QGIS directory`\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages.**

I had a shot at trying to install `shapely` to the QGIS-sub-version-specific version of Python while retaining my base Python as the one in the Windows environment variable PATH and PYTHONPATH: eventually I gave up and declared it a **GIGANTIC** PITFA. The hassle seemed to stem from the fact that the competing Python versions were both 2.7 variants.

For the present I've given up on a Pythonic solution, and instead have `bat`-ed a toggle for Windows PATH and PYTHONPATH: switch to QGIS' Python when QGIS starts, else revert to proper Python.

All just to run one plugin: plugin works real nice though - mah contours is real purdy.

If I get a chance to get a proper solution to my change-environment-variables-by-bat klunge, I'll update this answer.

Behold my contours...
[image: They sho' is purdy...]