# Use the contour plugin in QGIS without error message: python matplotlib not available

Tags: qgis, python, contour

I have recently downloaded the up to date stable version of QGIS (3.22.11) on my MacBook Pro. I downloaded the Contour plugin however when I try to use it I receive the message:

> python matplotlib not available

I've tried import numpy and import matplotlib in the Python console but that did not work.

Has anyone else had this problem or know a solution?

Comment: Please check this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/ccrook/QGIS-Contour-Plugin/issues/18 and also this thread: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158175/qgis-contour-plugin-says-no-shapely-can-import-shapely-in-qgis-console

Comment: Neither of these threads worked for me. I am able to import matplotlib, shapely, and numpy in the python console, however when I go to use the contour plugin I still receive the error: python matplotlib not available