# Install openpyxl in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I have built a plugin to try to read Excel files and save the chosen layer to CSV and I want to use [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/) in QGIS, but there is a error:

```
ImportError: No module named openpyxl
```

Comment: You might want to look at: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54674/how-to-install-the-python-module-shapely-for-qgis-use

Comment: QGIS can read Excel files. Why do you need that plug-in? Otherwise extend PYTHONPATH to avoid error message.